# Gym (openAI) environment actions space depends from actual state

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, keras-rl

I'm using gym toolkit to create my own env and keras-rl to use my env within an agent.
The problem is that my actions space changes, it depends from actual state. 
For example, i have 46 possible actions, but given a certain state only 7 are available, and i'm not able to find a way to modeling that.

I've read that question [open-ai-enviroment-with-changing-action-space-after-each-step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001361/open-ai-enviroment-with-changing-action-space-after-each-step)

but this did not resolve my problem.

In Gym Documentation there are not instructions to do this, only an issue on their Github repo (still open).
I can't understand how the agent (keras-rl, dqn agent) pick up an action, is it randomically choosen? but from where?

Can somebody help me? Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've handled this by just ignoring any invalid actions and letting the exploration mechanics keep it from getting stuck.  Quick and simple, but likely better ways to do it.

I think the better option is to somehow set the probability of selecting that action to zero, but I've had trouble figuring out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is enforcing this through the reward, making the agent learn which actions are appropriate given a certain state. You could for example highly penalize when an action the agent wants to take is not allowed. You should also not let it take the action if it isn't available in the current state.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could define a state variable inside your class and using the property action_space, change what is being returned. The action_space property is defined in the link you shared: [Is there a way to implement an OpenAI's environment, where the action space changes at each step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001361/is-there-a-way-to-implement-an-openais-environment-where-the-action-space-chan)